# Is Azure Machine Learning Studio Open Source?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is Azure Machine Learning Studio open source so I can contribute patches? Is so, where is the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. However, the various wrappers around it are.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out [ML.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning). This was open sourced recently and, as far as I know, is what Microsoft has been using the past few years in their products.

It's still in early preview as they port their internal code to be open source so a lot of the features aren't quite out yet. Given time, though, I believe this can be a powerful machine learning framework in C#.